# The FirefoxDriver cannot be used after quit() was called

Tags: java, maven, selenium, testng

I get this error when I run multiple test cases in my `maven` project using `TestNG`. Have tried multiple solutions but none worked for me.
The `FirefoxDriver` cannot be used after `quit()` was called.

MY steps are following:-

@Test1
So when I run my test cases the first case will run perfectly which involves
Open Browser
Input incorrect login details
close the browser.

@Test2
My second cases is
Opening browser
Logging in into application
Verify the URL
close the browser.

But in this case, it does not invoke my browser and gives me below error

> PASSED: loginfail       FAILED: loginpass
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.SessionNotFoundException: The FirefoxDriver
>   cannot be used after quit() was called. Build info: version: '2.53.1',
>   revision: 'a36b8b1cd5757287168e54b817830adce9b0158d', time:
>   '2016-06-30 19:26:09' System info: host: 'EIS011', ip: '192.168.0.18',
>   os.name: 'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3',
>   java.version: '1.8.0_111' Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver

Here is my code for your reference -

So this is my Testcases Class.
[image]

2) This is the class from where I'm calling my methods I'm using Page Object Model.

[image]

If you guys do not understand my question please let me know. Please help as I'm stuck in this for quite a few days now.

Answer (score 0):

You should not call `WebDriver.quit()` if you are going to run more tests; if you want to close the browser you should call just `WebDriver.close()`, which closes the browser but does not terminate the driver process.

Call `quit()` only after the last test. If you call `quit()` after each test, in order to run the next test you need to create a new instance of the driver, and I don't think there is much of a point in doing so.

Comment: Hey SantiBailors , Thanks a lot for replying but I tried doing that and when I use webDriver.close () then it shows me this error.                                          org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.

Comment: @piyushjolly I could not see calls to `close()` in your code, anyway it sounds like you are calling `close()` after you called `quit()`, which would be wrong. Just follow the order of calls I mentioned in my answer and post here possible errors you get from that. PS Names of methods and variables should start with lowercase, it's a well established convention that basically everybody follows.
PPS When posting code don't use a screenshot, just format the text as code by prefixing each line with 4 spaces, which also happens if you select the text and click the "code" button.

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs because all your `@Test` annotated test methods seem to be using the same `driver` instance and in one of your test methods you are calling `quit()` method. So the following test method tries to access a webdriver which is in an invalid state which explains the exception.

There are a couple of ways in which you can fix this problem.

1. Resort to using a `ThreadLocal` variant for your webdriver instance tracking, and push in a valid webdriver instance into it via either a `beforeInvocation()` (TestNG listener) or via a `@BeforeMethod` and clean up the threadlocal instance via a `afterInvocation()` or via an `@AfterMethod` method.
2. You move the webdriver instantiation and cleanup into your `@Test` method.